# Bazel: Integrating with npm projects?

Tags: javascript, npm, bazel, truffle, monorepo

I'm interested in using Google's open source [Bazel](https://bazel.build/) in my project.

My project is a **monorepo** that consists of three sub-projects:

- `Core` - A [truffle](http://truffleframework.com/) project.
- `Core.js` - A JavaScript library, which includes some build artifacts from `Core`.
- `Muse` - A `react` & `redux` frontend which uses `Core.js`.

I would like to use `Bazel` for the following:

1. Building the dependency chain as described.
2. Continuous integration & testing on [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org).
3. Generating documentation.
4. Automatically Deploying artifacts to `npm` and deploying `Core` using `truffle` upon releasing to a designated release branch.

A couple of questions:

1. How easily can `Bazel` integrate with existing (non-hermetic) build systems, such as: `webpack`, `truffle`, etc.. ?
2. What about cases in which I can't know the output files statically beforehand?
3. How much `Bazel` disrupts the directory structure and workflow that I'm used to with `npm` based projects?
4. Can it be used to do automatic deployments as described?
5. How complex/expertise is needed to make such a build system with `Bazel`?

Comment: What do you need to land in NPM? If you need core or core.js then can you explain why?

Comment: Core & Core.js are supposed to be npm libraries to be used by anyone.
Core is a smart contract library built with truffle, it's artifacts are the compiled contracts & source.
Core.js is an ordinary typescript library.

Comment: What I’m asking is who are “everyone”? In general Bazel favors building from source so if “everyone” is a group of people in your organization who use Bazel then you shouldn’t deploy core & core.js to npm. Just build them from source. If everyone is an external community then you indeed need npm

Comment: By everyone I mean all developers in the world who wish to use the library.